# I get this error even though I do have debuggable set: The application does not have the 'android:debuggable' attribute set in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-manifest

Problem: I get the following error when trying to run the Xamarin.Android application:
"he application does not have the 'android:debuggable' attribute set in the AndroidManifest.xml"

Even though I *do* have it set in the manifest:

```
<application android:label="SomeAPP" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/SOMETheme" android:icon="@drawable/some_icon_180px" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

I don't want to set it to true, because I am about to upload to the Google Play Store.
I also looked for debuggable in the entire project. It does not exist in any other files in this project.

Why is it still stating that?

Answer (score 0):

At first, the 'android:debuggable' attribute doesn't need the developer to set, it will be set as false when you run it in the release mode and as true when you run it in the debug mode.

And I have checked a number of my projects' AndroidManifest.xml, all of them don't have this attribute in the file.

You can try to create a new project to test this or update the packages you added into your project. The third-party package may cause this error.